# Green screen kinect

Tags: kinect

The green screen kinect sample which is available in SDK 1.5 is not showing the head part fully, whereas the hair part is coming with some blur effect.

I'm unable to see the hair portion in the sample. Is there any improved version of kinect green screen that is available?

Answer (score 1):

That is not problem of the sample. See this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BaWwx5x7nM

The Kinect project a IR grid to detect the depth, but some "rays" pass through the space amoung the hair so can not detect that part.

It's possible "fill" that missing part, but you have to implement by yourself.